# Inferring the type of a constant array

Tags: typescript-generics

Consider the following:

```
type ArrayOf<T> = T extends (infer R)[] ? R : never;
const a = ['a', 'b'];
type A = ArrayOf<typeof a>;
```

Type `A` is a synonym of `string`, which is what I want.

But:

```
type ArrayOf<T> = T extends (infer R)[] ? R : never;
const a = ['a', 'b'] as const;
type A = ArrayOf<typeof a>;
```

make the type `A` a synonym of... `never`, which is not what I want.  I want it to be `'a' | 'b'`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`['a', 'b'] as const` is of type `readonly ['a', 'b']`, which does not extend `T[]`, but does extend `readonly T[]`. The difference is that a `readonly T[]` does not have methods that allow you to mutate the array (like `push`).

The correct definition of `ArrayOf<T>` is

```
type ArrayOf<T> = T extends readonly (infer R)[] ? R : never;
```